# Get the amount of lines outputted in a Win32 console?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make my own function to clear a console output column, using some amateur C programming. I want to get the amount of lines in the console output when I call my function so that I can move the cursor to the specified column in each line, rewrite that space on that column as a blank space, and go to the next line. Unfortunately, I have no way to end the loop when it reaches the last line.

How should I get the amount of lines in the current console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you `#include <Windows.h>` you can do this by doing:

```
HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO screen;

GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console, &screen);
```

And then accessing the dimensions is as simple as typing `screen.dwSize.X` (width) & `screen.dwSize.Y` (height), but this poses a problem, the size of the `X` or `Y` dimensions is not nessicarially the size of the buffer being displayed.

So on my PC, if i do:

```
printf("X:%d - Y:%d\n", screen.dwSize.X, screen.dwSize.Y);
```

It displays `X:80 - Y:1000` when the visible Y size is only 25 but i can scroll through a length of 1000.

How you get the current visible output size i'm not sure, but here is a function that clears the entire screen buffer:

```
void clearScreen(void) {
    COORD topLeft  = { 0, 0 };
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO screen;
    DWORD written;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console, &screen);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacterA(
        console, ' ', screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written
    );
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
        console, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
        screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written
    );
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, topLeft);
}
```

And a simple gotoxy function for cursor control:

```
void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    COORD cursorPos = {x,y};
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, cursorPos);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few steps needed to initialize things, but the call that gives the information you are looking for is [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

At a minimum, you need a *handle* (file-descriptor) pointing to the console.  You can do that with [GetStdHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), e.g.,

```
HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```